# how to passing data different component that are not parent and child component

Tags: angular, router

i have 3 component that are app.component ,body.component,detail,component.
when i in detailcomponet click button ,
i want app.component loginame  equal detailcomponet logname
i m use a service share data to communicate two component ,i could passing data to the service ,but appcompont could not effect.
app and detail component

[image]

service and router and body component

[image]

Comment: Use a shared service to share data between components that are not direct parent-child or siblings. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: i just modify code use shared service this method,  i could passed data to the service ,console.log confirm it. but could not effect to the app component. could bother you  have time to see it . i paste two picture  above it .thank u very much ,app constructor :constructor(private psservice:Passservice){
  psservice.passdata$.subscribe(
   shardata =>{
    this.loginname=shardata;
        //this.loginname='haha "${shardata}"  hellow';
        //console.log(shardata);
   });

Comment: If you add the service to each component, then each component will get a different service instance. Either add it to providers of a component that is a parent of both or add to providers of `@NgModule()` then one service instance will be shared with the whole application.

Comment: i  use app module providers add this service instead other component . it worked well,  very helpful to me ,thank u very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the service to each component, then each component will get a different service instance. Either add it to providers of a component that is a parent of both or add to providers of @NgModule() then one service instance will be shared with the whole application.